# Oracle: can I return a list of lists in query or in procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to return list of lists in select query. I can return ODCIVarchar2List by this query:

```
SELECT sys.ODCIVarchar2List(av.ATTRIBUTE_ID, av.VALUE) l
    FROM USERS u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIBUTES a ON a.CONTRACT_ID = u.CONTRACT_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIBUTE_VALUES av ON (av.USER_ID = u.USER_ID) AND (av.ATTRIBUTE_ID = a.ATTRIBUTE_ID)
    WHERE u.USER_ID = '123'
```

The result is like:

```
1 {attr1, val1}
2 {attr2, val2}
```

I want to get:

```
1 {{attr1, val1},{attr2,val2}}
```

Is it possible to make something like?

```
SELECT sys.ODCISomekingOfList(l) ll FROM (query above)
```

Are there other solutions? I know it's possible in postgresql. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, define any type you want and return that. Do you want a collection of collections, or a collection of rows?

Comment: Your example shows a json output. Not sure if it is an option but Oracle has native functions for that (JSON_OBJECT, JSON_ARRAY, JSON_ARRAYAGG, etc). You can nest these functions and convert scalar data into the json representation of your choice. Check the docs for your version of oracle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare a user-defined type and nest lists as many times as you want:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
CREATE TYPE string_list_list AS TABLE OF string_list;
```

Then use:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         COLLECT(
           string_list(av.ATTRIBUTE_ID, av.VALUE)
           ORDER BY av.ATTRIBUTE_ID
         )
         AS string_list_list
       ) as list_of_lists
FROM   USERS u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIBUTES a
       ON a.CONTRACT_ID = u.CONTRACT_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ATTRIBUTE_VALUES av
       ON  av.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
       AND av.ATTRIBUTE_ID = a.ATTRIBUTE_ID
WHERE  u.USER_ID = '123'
```

You can also perform the aggregation using JSON or XML functions and return the result in those formats (rather than as nested collections).

---

> Is it possible to make something like?
>
> ```sql
> SELECT sys.ODCISomekingOfList(l) ll FROM (query above)
> ```

Theoretically, yes, you could define a user-defined type in the `SYS` schema as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE SYS.ODCISomethingOfList AS VARRAY(32767) OF SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
```

*(I made it a `VARRAY` since the other ODCI types are also `VARRAY`s rather than nested tables but you could do either.)*

Then you can use the query above replacing `string_list` with `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` and `string_list_list` with `SYS.ODCISomethingOfList`.

However, as a general rule, you should **NEVER** modify the `SYS` schema as you run the risk of inadvertently breaking the database. Just use user-defined types in your own schema.